# Getting error while using with_items and when in ansible, could you please assist

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check the file exist and take a backup of a file

```
   tasks:
    - name: Check the file existence
      stat:
        path: "{{item.file}}"
      register: "{{item.name}}"
      with_items:
        - { name: shadow, file: /etc/shadow }
        - { name: sudoers, file: /etc/sudoers }

    - name: Backing up the /etc/shadow and /etc/sudoers
      shell: cp -p "{{item.file}}" "{{item.file}}".$(date +%Y%m%d)
      when: item.when.stat.exists
      with_items:
        - { file: /etc/shadow, when: "shadow" }
        - { file: /etc/sudoers, when: "sudoers" }
```

> **error:** 
>    fatal: [c369hmx]: FAILED! => {
>       "msg": "The conditional check 'item.when.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.when.stat.exists): 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/m6080995/temproot/fileexis.yaml': line 16, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    #- name: Backing up the /etc/shadow and /etc/sudoers\n    - shell: cp -p \"{{item.file}}\" \"{{item.file}}\".$(date +%Y%m%d)\n      ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"

Thank you for your time
Now I modified playbook, but getting error

---

- name: testing stat module
  hosts: all
  user: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:

  - name: Check the file exists
    stat:
      path: "{{item}}"
    register: result
    loop:

    - /etc/shadow
    - /etc/sudoers
  - set_fact:
      my_stat: "{{ dict(result.results|json_query('[].[item.stat.exists]')) }}"
  - debug:
      var: my_stat
  - name: Backing up the /etc/shadow and /etc/sudoers
    shell: cp -p "{{ item }}" "{{ item }}".$(date +%Y%m%d)
    when: my_stat[item]|bool
    loop:

    - /etc/shadow
    - /etc/sudoers
      ~
      the above is playbook

error:

ERROR! The field 'loop' is supposed to be a string type, however the incoming data structure is a

The error appears to have been in '/home/m6080995/temproot/fileexis.yaml': line 7, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
tasks:
  - name: Check the file existence
    ^ here
```

Comment: Please check the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Register `result` in a single variable and create a dictionary with the status of the files. For example

```
    - name: Check the file existence
      stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      register: result
      loop:
        - data/shadow
        - data/sudoers

    - set_fact:
        my_stat: "{{ dict(result.results|json_query('[].[item,stat.exists]')) }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_stat
```

give

```
    "my_stat": {
        "data/shadow": true, 
        "data/sudoers": true
    }
```

Then the condition is trivial

```
    - name: Backing up the /etc/shadow and /etc/sudoers
      shell: cp -p "{{ item }}" "{{ item }}".$(date +%Y%m%d)
      when: my_stat[item]|bool
      loop:
        - data/shadow
        - data/sudoers
```

gives

```
shell> ls -1 data
shadow
shadow.20200311
sudoers
sudoers.20200311
```

Use `copy` module instead of `shell`. For example

```
    - copy:
        remote_src: true
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ item ~ '.' ~ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
      when: my_stat[item]|bool
      loop:
        - data/shadow
        - data/sudoers
```

gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

still getting error:

ERROR! The field 'loop' is supposed to be a string type, however the incoming data structure is a

The error appears to have been in '/home/m6080995/temproot/fileexis.yaml': line 7, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
tasks:
  - name: Check the file existence
    ^ here
```

the below is the playbook

---

- name: testing stat module
  hosts: all
  user: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:

  - name: Check the file exists
    stat:
      path: "{{item}}"
    register: result
    loop:

    - /etc/shadow
    - /etc/sudoers
  - set_fact:
      my_stat: "{{ dict(result.results|json_query('[].[item.stat.exists]')) }}"
  - debug:
      var: my_stat
  - name: Backing up the /etc/shadow and /etc/sudoers
    shell: cp -p "{{ item }}" "{{ item }}".$(date +%Y%m%d)
    when: my_stat[item]|bool
    loop:

    - /etc/shadow
    - /etc/sudoers